# C program doesn't work correctly

Tags: c, alphabet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void main()
{
    char alfavita[30] =
    {
        'a',
        'b',
        'c',
        'd',
        'e',
        'f',
        'g',
        'h',
        'i',
        'j',
        'k',
        'l',
        'm',
        'n',
        'o',
        'p',
        'q',
        'r',
        's',
        't',
        'u',
        'v',
        'w',
        'x',
        'y',
        'z'
    };

    char str[20];


    printf("Give a word:\n");
    gets(str);


    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<strlen(alfavita);j++)
            if(alfavita[j] == str[i])
                str[i] = alfavita[j+3];
    }



    puts(str);
}
```

For example if i give 'a' it should be return 'd' (each letter will transform into the 3d next of the alfavita array ) But it just prints me a null string. I can't find something wrong or I don't see it .

Comment: What did you find out so far, such that we don't waste precious time on things you have already verified?

Comment: `str[i]` is the ASCII value for the character at that point. When fed with a lowercase character such as `a`, it's looking for a 97th entry.

Comment: You can have out of bound error on inputs like 'zzz'; something like `(j+3) % 30` should be used

Comment: what if `if(alfavita[j] == str[i])` become true when `j` index point last character.

Comment: You can define alfavita as `char alfavita[30] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc"`

Answer (score 1):

`str[i] = alfavita[j+3];`
After this line the code continues, so it will put i+3, i+6, ... until it gets out of alfavita.
You can add a `break` to exit the inner loop like that:

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)    
{
    for(int j=0;j<strlen(alfavita);j++)
        if(alfavita[j] == str[i])
        {
            str[i] = alfavita[j+3];
            break;  // next i.
        }
}
```

, or maybe just directly access the array:

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
{
  char c = str[i];
  if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
    str[i] = alfavita[(c - 'a' + 3) % strlen(alfavita)];
  }
}
```

Note the `% strlen(alfavita)` to avoid ending after the end of the list.
You could also write it:

```
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
  str[i] = ((c - 'a' + 3) % 26) + 'a';
}
```

Comment: It's pretty bad form to recommend code that locks the program to a particular encoding. You cannot assume that the letters are continuously laid out.

Comment: Strictly reading the standard that's true, though I don't know any C encoding where the letters a to z are not contiguous.

Comment: [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) is the standard example. Of course it's not widely used, but it does exist.

Comment: So you can make a slow code that will run on every machine, or a faster code that works only on 99.99 % of the machines...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table that gives the replacement character for each character.

Then encode by computing the index into `plain`, and transferring that index into `encoded`:

```
char encode_char(char c)
{
  const char *plain   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const char *encoded = "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc";

  const char *pp = strchr(plain, c);
  if(pp != NULL)
    return encoded[(ptrdiff_t) (pp - plain)];
  return '?';
}
```

How the above works:

1. Define two strings that are supposed to be 1:1 mapped, i.e. `plain[0]` is encoded into `encoded[0]`. This can be more clearly modelled (i.e. by a `struct` that has the pair) but then the iniialization becomes more complicated.
2. Search for the input character `c` inside the `plain` string. This returns `NULL` if not found, or a pointer to somewhere inside `plain` found.
3. Make sure the pointer isn't `NULL` before using its value.
4. Subtract `plain` (i.e. `&plain[0]`, the address of the `a`) from `pp`. This evaluates to 0 for `a`, 1 for `b`, and so on.
5. Use the computed index to look up the corresponding character in `encoded`.
6. On failure to encode, return `?`.

In a portable, general program, you *can not* use plain subtraction (i.e. `c - 'a'`), since C **does not** guarantee that characters are encoded in values next to each other.

As pointed out, the above assumes that each character encodes in exactly one `char`. That might not be true for targets with exotic encodings, in which case it really is safer to use an explicit table, like this:

```
const struct {
  char plain;
  char encoded;
} encoding[] = {
 { 'a', 'd' },
 { 'b', 'e' },
 { 'c', 'f' },
 /* ... and so on ... */
};
```

The encoding function then becomes:

```
char encode_char2(char c)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof encoding / sizeof *encoding; ++i)
  {
    if(encoding[i].plain == c)
      return encoding[i].encoded;
  }
  return '?';  /* Not found. */
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer a little? To me it seems like `pp - plain` should be replaced with `*pp - 'a'` or I am missing something.

Comment: pp is pointer (char*) to the found character, plain is a pointer to the beginning of the plain string, so pp - plain is the difference between the points, that's an offset within the string. encoded[offset] is valid, you could also write *(encoded + offset).

Comment: This approach will not work with UTF-8 variable lengh encoding though.

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux But a..z all encode in a single byte in UTF-8.

Comment: Sure, but if you use UTF-8 it's usually to add extra characters.

Comment: @Nicolas: so you can make a slow routine that works for every possible encoding, or a fast one that works as asked for `a..z`.